# why is apple App Store icon showing up as white

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have uploaded an app onto the apple store through iTunes connect with the app icon size 1024x1024 in the assets.xcassets folder and by manually uploading it in iTunes connect. However after my app has been approved for an update, the icon shows up as white when in the App Store but when downloaded the Icon is there. Is there anyway to figure out a fix for this? I am not sure as to why this has happened as I have uploaded the app with zero issues with the icon 3 times before. [image: here is the problem][image: I tunes connect picture]

Comment: try downloading app in another device

Comment: @PinkeshGjr When downloaded the app shows the icon,  but when searched in the actual apple store it just shows a white box

Comment: please share appstore itunes connect screenshot and assets

Comment: @pinkeshGjr I have updated my post with a picture of I tunes connect showing both the assets included and the App Store icon

Comment: It's also not showing up for me when I search your app on the App Store.

Comment: Maybe try to push another update. Just archive and upload the same thing again with a different build number and come up with a "fix" you did 

Comment: You shouldn't have to upload a new icon every time you push an update to your app.  Did you change the icon at all, or is it the exact same file you used before?  If the file was not changed (meaning you didn't re-save the file as a new PNG), I'm guessing something corrupted it during the upload / propagation step where it gets distributed out to all the regional datastores used by the App Store.  As a note, I see the app in the App Store with the all white icon.

Comment: @wottle I have already pushed a quick update and that has not worked, I have not changed the icon at all. This is interesting because it has worked fine for the first 3 updated and now with 4 and the quick 5 the icon on just the store is white. Maybe I will have to call apple and see why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer, I just deleted and then re uploaded the app store logo in assets and then reuploaded my project under a different build number and it now shows up on the app store